# How to download entire Youtube channel using commands or application

Tags: downloads, youtube

I want to download entire Youtube channel using Ubuntu, but i can't find way to download, any help appreciate !

Comment: @Ufoguy Youtube has also locked down most normal downloader methods recently.  However if you read further there's a duplicate question for this so it's irrelevant about my old comment here.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The other question does not even talk about channels. How to "un-duplicate"?